# How to avoid extensive error handling code on every layer in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, exception, if-statement, readability, nserror

In Objective C, how do I avoid having all this extensive error handling in my methods? I've read that Apple suggest that NSError references should be used only when errors are expected, but this approach causes the code to be completely cluttered with error handling code.

[Apples guide to Exceptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html)

There is especially one sentence in this document that catches my eye;

> a parsing library might use exceptions internally to indicate problems and enable a quick exit from a parsing state that could be deeply recursive; however, you should take care to catch such exceptions at the top level of the library and translate them into an appropriate return code or state

This is an (incomplete and unoptimized) snippet of code demonstrating what I mean. Every call I make within my method requires error checking on every step, cluttering the code with if statements and making it hard to read.

```
- (NSNumber) countFriendsForUserName:(NSString*) userName error:(NSError **)error {
    NSError *internalError = nil;
    Session *session = [_sessionMgr openSessionWithError:&internalError];
    if (!error) {
        User *user = [session findUserByName:userName error:&internalError];
       if (!error) {
           NSArray * bestFriends = [session getFriendsByUserId:user.id error:&internalError];
       }
    }
    [_sessionMgr closeSession];        
    if (internalError) {
        *error=internalError;
        return 0;
    } 
    return [bestFriends count];
}
```

If I were to use exceptions instead, the code would look something like this (again, this piece of code is just an incomplete example), I don't have XCode in front of me at the moment.

```
- (NSNumber) countFriendsForUserName:(NSString*) userName error:(NSError **)error {
    @try{
        Session *session = [_sessionMgr openSession];
        User *user = [session findUserByName:userName];
        NSArray * bestFriends = [session getFriendsByUserId:user.id];
        [_sessionMgr closeSession];  
        return [bestFriends count];            
    } 
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        [_sessionMgr closeSession];        
        *error=[ExceptionParser createNSErrorFromException:e];
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

If I interpret Apples Exceptions guidelines correctly, if my code is behaving like a "parsing library" (Apples example) it might be totally ok to use exceptions internally, and just translate them before I return to the calling function, which then in turn might act on my NSError codes to take appropriate action. Or have I misunderstood Apples guidelines?

Answer (score 3):

You should test the return value of the method, not the existence of the `NSError` object.  Also you can chain the `NSError` objects to return the low-level error back to the caller:

```
- (NSInteger)countFriendsForUserName:(NSString*)userName
                               error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSArray *bestFriends = nil;
    Session *session = [_sessionMgr openSessionWithError:error];
    if (session) {
        User *user = [session findUserByName:userName error:error];
        if (user) {
           bestFriends = [session getFriendsByUserId:user.id error:error];
        }
    }
    [_sessionMgr closeSession];
    return [bestFriends count];
}
```

Note:

- Moved `bestFriends` to the top of the method.
- Changed return type.

Comment: you type faster than me ;)

Comment: Those are very valid points. But I'm still curious why Exceptions would not be better instead? The code would not require any if statements at all, and at the last step, before returning a result to the application (and user) the exception would be translated into an NSError that the application user UI could interpret.

Comment: You should use exceptions for exceptional conditions.  If a method returns a value, and that returned value is `NO` or `nil` or whatever, then that is not necessarily an error.  It merely means the thing being looked for does not exist, and that is not an error if you want to see if you need to add that thing or not.  Exceptions are also expensive and cumbersome to handle at a fine-grained level.

Comment: Note also that ARC is not exception-safe. You will leak memory in ObjC if you throw exceptions. This is normally ok, since it is expected that you will crash soon after throwing an exception. The guidance in the Exception Handling guide pre-dates ARC. If you compile as ObjC++ (or if you pass certain flags to the compiler), you will get memory-safe exceptions, but there are performance impacts (both memory and time) to this, and it is not encouraged.